# IdentityServer3: protect asp.net mvc app from unauthorized access

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, identityserver3, claims-based-identity, openid-connect

The environment is on single sign on with identityserver3. I have a client angular application which is using openid connect with identityserver 3. I also have a file viewer asp.net mvc application which is used to render pdfs and other files and has no security. The angular app renders the fileviewer inside an iframe to show the contents of files.

I tried adding the file viewer as a client to identity with openid connect so that when a user is signed in to the angular app the user would be single signed into the file viewer app also but it doesn't work in the iframe when file viewer redirects to identity's authorize endpoint due to the x-frame-options sameorigin header. If I open the file viewer url is a separate tab and then launch the file preview within the angular app then calls within the angular app start working as the file viewer cookies are now in the browser.

Ideally I'd like the file viewer to work just like a web api which only validates incoming tokens but not sure how to achieve that with identity server.

How do I go about securing the file viewer application with identityserver? Do I have to manually decode the jwt token by using messagehandlers in the pipeline?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you were rendering the file locally you could use bearer auth, like webapi does. However because you're using MVC in an iframe, it's slightly trickier. You'll need to trigger the auth for the file viewer in a new window - SSO login should never happen in an iframe. This should then give you auth credentials, usually a cookie, for when you call the file viewer mvc app in your iframe.